# Are there Bookmarks with selection highlighted in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have a search query on the attribute table which highlights the features and then zooms to that particular layer. I take a bookmark for this particular view with the selection being highlighted. 
But later when I see the same bookmark it does not highlight those selected features.Any settings or any other plugin for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The bookmark only saves the extent but not the information about selection.

You can permanently save selections by exporting the selection to a new file: Right-click in layer list an choose "Save selection as ...".

Comment: Ok, doesnt serve my purpose completely to save each selection as a different layer.Thanks.